# Automatically build latest PHP patch version in Docker?

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

`Dockerfile` contains`FROM php:7.3-apache-stretch`.

How to tell Docker to automatically build `7.3.1` from Docker Hub (latest patch version as of this writing) when I run the build command?

E.g., Next time when PHP is `7.3.2`, I simply run build without specifying specific patch version or `apt-get update...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the tags -> php:7.3-apache-stretch will always be the latest of the 7.3.x branch.

to rebuild for a new version you have to rebuild your image (it will then automatically take the latest version of the tag)

`docker build --pull .`

for docker compose it is not possible to automatically pull new images -> so you have to call `docker pull YOUR_BASE_IMAGE` before

`docker-compose up --build`

Comment: I tried it `docker-compose up --build` however it's still showing `7.3.0` in `phpinfo()`.

Comment: can you post then the docker file you are using? It should use 7.3.1 per definition - you can try to call `docker pull php:7.3-apache-stretch`

Comment: `docker pull` did it. Does that mean I need to run `docker pull` every time there's a PHP update?

Comment: there is a `--no-cache` option on docker build that you can use

Comment: I'm pretty sure `--no-cache` does something different and you need to explicitly `docker pull`.  (It prevents Docker from remembering that it already did a specific `RUN` step, but doesn't make it go out and look for a newer image with the same tag.)

Comment: yes @DavidMaze you are right - the right attribute is `--pull`